# How to record video only in portrait in iOS but not in landscape?

Tags: swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, video-capture

I want to allow user to record a video only in portrait mode(orientation) and restrict the user to record in landscape. I'm using UIImagePickerController and I couldn't find any orientation options in it. could anyone help me out in this?

Comment: You will have to restrict user from project setting in Xcode.

Comment: @Kudos Yes, we have added supported interface orientations as portrait. But still user can able to record video in portrait. Could you please share if you have any info?

Comment: Do you mean " still user can able to record video in Landscape"?

Comment: yes, it's auto rotating @Kudos

Comment: Please check My Answer.. I have tested it in my CameraVC

Answer (score 0):

Write below code in `AppDelegate`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    guard let mainController = navigationController else { return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all }
    if ((mainController.visibleViewController as? CameraVC) != nil) == false {
        //This VC should support only Portrait Mode.
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
    } else {
        //Else support All Modes.
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
    }
}
```

And It will Restrict Your "`CameraVC`" to Rotate in landscape Mode.